# ZyXEL ADSL home router showing up as 4 WLAN networks

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, adsl

When I enable WLAN in my new ZyXEL ADSL modem/router and configure it with the SSID and WPA2-PSK password that I want, it works just fine. The problem is that instead of the single WLAN access point that I need, it emits four. The three others are named ZyXEL_2, ZyXEL_3 and ZyXEL_4 and they have NO security enabled. Some unknown neighbour has an access point named ZyXEL (it has a clearly weaker signal as seen from here). It shows up as unsecured as well. I can't figure out from the configuration interface how to turn this off. None of the WDS links are configured or ticked as being active. I'm not sure what is happening here.

Device Name: ZyXEL P-660HN-T1A Internet Sharing Gateway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently these "extra" SSIDs are part of the multiple Basic Service Sets (BSSs) provided by the ZyXEL.  You should be able to disable these in the "More AP" configuration screen/page by clearing the three "Active" check boxes.

> Network > Wireless LAN > More AP

P.S.  Looks like an interesting unit.  Are you in the USA?

Comment: Thanks! I feel kind of dumb for not opening that particular configuration page before. I'm in northern Europe. The unit was reasonably priced. It didn't recognize the correct ADSL settings automatically though, I had to input them manually.